# extjs 4.1 converting a dynamic combobox into dynamic radiogroup

Tags: extjs, extjs4

After loading in a store of user roles [id, name] I can easily make the following form field which dynamically populates a drop down list of roles (User, Admin, ...)

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    name: 'roleIds',
    queryMode: 'local',
    pinList: false,
    fieldLabel: 'Role',
    store: 'Roles',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    allowBlank: false
}
```

This works fine but what are the proper steps required to turn this into a radiogroup?  How do I make sure the proper radio button is selected when editing a record?  How do I specify the default when the form is empty and making a new user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically very similar thing. At the end you need to have something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Two Columns',
    // Arrange radio buttons into two columns, distributed vertically
    columns: 2,
    vertical: true,
    items: [
        { boxLabel: 'Item 1', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1' },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 2', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2', checked: true},
        { boxLabel: 'Item 3', name: 'rb', inputValue: '3' },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 4', name: 'rb', inputValue: '4' },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 5', name: 'rb', inputValue: '5' },
        { boxLabel: 'Item 6', name: 'rb', inputValue: '6' }
    ]
}
```

So after you receive data from the server, do a simple loop and create array of items (each items is `Ext.form.field.Radio` and then create a radio group and pass this array in.

Comment: i had to loop through the store array and create an items array with boxLabel, name, and inputValue as shown above.